# PHP include/require a different extension file as .php

Tags: php, javascript, apache

I have a .js file with code compatible for both php and js languages. The file is read and edited by php and then fetched by JS. so the extension is JS, is there any way that i can require this file in my php script and the file may execute normally as a require/include would work on a .php file.

I dont want to Eval the file contents in PHP because Eval is time costly and risky.

SO is there any way to include/require non php extension files as a php file ?

edit : the files content are similar to the text below, this file is read/written by php and then included in my page via simple js file inclusion as

```
$my_array = Array();
$my_array['id_01'] = 100;
```

Comment: Did you ever try to include it before going to stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question but if this can help : you can call a JS via PHP this way : `<script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.php"></script>` if your _jsFile.php_ got `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
` (And you can even add GET parameters)

Comment: (And yeah, I know it's not an `include` ... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a .js file with code compatible for both php and js languages

hmmm, yes it is possible but I suspect your code is **NOT** compatible. Include/require works regardless of what the file extension is.

> s there any way that i can require this file in my php script and the file may execute normally as a require/include would work on a .php file

You seem to think it's not compatible either.

Your post is so confused its hard to tell what you're really trying to achieve here - but the following code is valid in both languages and would execute where the relevant functions are defined:

```
// <?php

hello_world("I am bilingual!");
```

Comment: wow i am getting some hints here, what i did was not adding the <?php in that js file, a big mistake, but will this code block work in both? when included via php and when called as a js

// <?php

hello_world("I am bilingual!");

Comment: how can I manage with <?php, to work only when it is included via php

Comment: The problem with your example, @symcbean is that if `hello_world()` outputs anything, it will be on the same line as the comment. Could be fixed by `print()` or `echo` ing a line break: `echo "\n";` before any output is generated.

Comment: @shotsinger: If I was trying to create a javascript file from a php script then yes - but read my post again - I've written code which runs in both PHP javascript - not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

In an .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js
```

Make sure you set the header content type to `application/javascript` before you output anything:

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```

*EDIT*

After reading the edited question I think I understand.

If you take a JavaScript file which has PHP within it:

```
<?php

$var = 'this is a example';

?>
var foo = 'javascript bar';
```

You can include this file into a PHP script and access the variable `$var`, however whatever is outside of the `<?php ?>` will be outputted to the screen.  You could then include this same exact file as a javascript src file and access the variable `foo` from within JavaScript.  I have no idea why you would actually want to do this though.

If you tell us what you are trying to accomplish we might be able to offer alternate solutions.

Comment: Whoever down voted, feel free to leave a comment explaining why.  This was the original answer to the question before he edited.

Answer (score 0):

Any file of any kind can be `included`/`required`, including images.  To PHP, it's all relatively just text.  All that matters to be able to execute PHP code is what's inside the `<?php ?>` block.  When `included`, all text found within the open/close tags will be executed as PHP, while anything outside will render as normal text.

To test this out, simply open a .JPG file in notepad, add `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to the very end, save, then `include` this file in a PHP script like you would a PHP script file.  You'll see a jumble of text, but after that, the full phpinfo dump.  You can even use `Content-type: image/jpg` header to output the page as a true image, but the full phpinfo dump will stil be hidden within.

Edit: be sure to properly label your mime type on your outputted page, as evolve said above, as a courtesy to the site visitor.

Answer (score -1):

In your apache configuration:

```
AddHandler php-script .js
```

This tells apache to handle *.js files as PHP scripts.

Comment: But then he wouldn't be able to use it on the client side as a JS or any other JS for that matter.

Comment: should still work as long as JS code isn't inside <?php ?> blocks, and the user isn't viewing the .JS file directly as the HREF.

Comment: @Alin, Fosco is right, it has to be run through the PHP processor.

Comment: and Fosco, But the PHP code has to be inside <?php ?> blocks so it can be included ;).

Comment: okay I get it, I think I shouldnt use this approach then coz I dont want to make such an .htaccess change for this thing, I'll keep my data as a json string then, will have the overhead of json_decode and json_encode while editing of the file but i guess there is no other solution